# assign data.frame as a component in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

This does not work

```
> dfi=data.frame(v1=c(1,1),v2=c(2,2))
> dfi
  v1 v2
1  1  2
2  1  2
> df$df=dfi
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "df", value = list(v1 = c(1, 1), v2 = c(2,  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
```

`df$df=I(dfi)` has the same error. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want the contents of dfi passed to df use this code: df<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 2, dimnames=list(c(), c("V1", "V2"))), stringsAsFactors=F)

df=dfi

Comment: Data frames that contain data frames is an extremely unusual thing to do, and almost nothing in R will have been designed to work with a data structure in that format.

Comment: it could be part of a list which is quite common though.  Quite sure you are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Moved this from comments for formatting reasons:

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want the contents of dfi passed to df you can use this code:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 2, dimnames=list(c(), c("V1", "V2"))), stringsAsFactors=F)

df=dfi
```

Answer (score 0):

As @joran says, it is unclear why you would ever want to do this. Nevertheless, it is possible.

One of the requirements of a data frame is that all the columns have the same number of rows. This is why you are getting the error. Something like this will work:

```
dfi   <- data.frame(v1=c(1,1),v2=c(2,2))  # 2 rows
df    <- data.frame(x=1:2)                # also 2 rows
df$df <- dfi                              # works now
```

Printing would lead you to believe that `df` has three columns...

```
df
#   x df.v1 df.v2
# 1 1     1     2
# 2 2     1     2
```

but it does not!

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x : int  1 2
#  $ df:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ v1: num  1 1
#   ..$ v2: num  2 2
```

Since `df$df` is a data frame

```
class(df$df)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

you can use the standard data frame accessors...

```
df$df$v1
# [1] 1 1
df$df[1,]
#   v1 v2
# 1  1  2
```

Incidentally, RStudio has trouble displaying this type of data structure; `view(df)` gives an inaccurate display of the structure.

Finally, you are probably better off creating a list of data frames, rather than a data frame containing data frames:

```
df <- data.frame(grp=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=5),x=rnorm(15),y=rpois(15,5))
df.lst <- split(df,df$grp)    # creates a list of data frames
df.lst$A
#   grp          x  y
# 1   A -1.3606420 10
# 2   A -0.4511408  5
# 3   A -1.1951950  4
# 4   A -0.8017765  5
# 5   A -0.2816298  9
df.lst$A$x
# [1] -1.3606420 -0.4511408 -1.1951950 -0.8017765 -0.2816298
```